# $f$ is Holomorphic on an open ball, then the value of integration over the boundary of that open ball is zero.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Let,

$f\in H(B(0,R))$  and $f\in C(B[0,R])$, let  $$ T_R(t)=Re^{it}$$,

My problem is to show that$$\int_{T_R}f=0$$

It is easy to say, for any closed path inside the circle, the value of integration is $0$, by Cauchy theorem. i.e $$\int_{T_r}f=0, r<R$$.

But How to say the integration value is zero even on the boundary?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: the integral over the circle of radius $R-\epsilon$ is $0$ for  every $\epsilon >0$. Use uniform continuity of $f$ on the closed disk to prove that this integral tends to the integral over the circle of radius $R$ as $\epsilon \to 0$.